# File or path to database in prometheus where alerts are stored in json or other format that reflects in grafana

Tags: prometheus, alert, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

**What did you do?**
I am not sure whether this is right forum to ask this questions but I am looking for file or path to database in prometheus where alerts are stored in json or other format that reflects in grafana. I want to write a scripts to take some actions based on alerts/triggers. Normally alerts can be seen on dashboard and notified accordingly on email or messages. My concerns is to trace the path from where the alerts are relflected in grafana.

**What did you expect to see?**
I expect to have path to database or any json file in which alerts are populated on run time.

**Environment
System information:**

Linux 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64

**Prometheus version:**

prometheus, version 2.30.0-rc.0 (branch: HEAD, revision: 05a816b)
build user: root@438506e6c112
build date: 20210909-13:31:07
go version: go1.17
platform: linux/amd64

**Alertmanager version:**

alertmanager, version 0.20.0 (branch: HEAD, revision: f74be0400a6243d10bb53812d6fa408ad71ff32d)
build user: root@00c3106655f8
build date: 20191211-14:13:14
go version: go1.13.5

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Prometheus sends HTTP POST requests every time an evaluated alert rule is true. As far as I know, alerts are not saved on disk. The data that Prometheus sends out is a JSON, an example of which you may find in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787302/does-prometheus-supports-webhooks/70791409#70791409

Comment: @anemyte do you know about the entry in database table that caters for alerts?

Comment: Prometheus is not a relational database, there are no tables. Although, it turns out alerts are actually saved as time series and can be retrieved with the `ALERTS` query.

Comment: @anemyte so this means that if I want to extract alerts in file I would need to use grafana API for getting alert stats.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: I've spoken about Prometheus, not Grafana. Both Grafana and Prometheus have their own independent alerts and databases. I guess you have to find your what exactly you want to get, because Grafana, for example does use a relational database with tables, while Prometheus has its own no-SQL TSDB.

Comment: @anemyte we add data sources such as prometheus in grafana while its configs, that where i am referring to. We write queries in promql to get metrics and visualize them on grafana. I get my answer.